# Calling a list index within a loop using names()

Tags: r, list, loops

I have a list `aa` which references the index names of another list `bb` as well as containing one other element (call it `cm`). List `bb` items contain strings. I have a loop that goes through `bb` and, for every item which matches a string I've specified, adds it to a new row in a dataframe. What I need is to also add the `cm` value to that row.

Example:

```
library("tidyverse")

aa <- list(c(123, 1), c(234, 1), c(345, 2), c(456, 3))
bb <- list("123" = c("a", "b", "c"), "234" = c("b", "c", "d"), "345" = c("c", "d", "e"), "456" = c("f", "g", "h"))
cc <- c("a", "b", "c")

tbl <- NULL
for (a in aa){
  for (b in bb) {
      if (any(cc %in% b)) {
        tb <- tibble(cm=a[2],n1=b[1],n2=b[2],n3=b[3])
        tbl <- bind_rows(tbl,tb)
      }
    }
  }
```

This iterates through for every possible combination of `bb`, and adds it to pairs it to every `cm`, which is no good. My output should look something like this:

```
output <- tibble(cm = c(1, 1, 2), n1 = c("a", "b", "c"),
             n2 = c("b", "c", "d"), n3 = c("c", "d", "e"))

> output
# A tibble: 3 x 4
         cm    n1    n2    n3
      <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1         1     a     b     c
2         1     b     c     d
3         2     c     d     e
```

I thought maybe something like this would work, as at least then I could loop through `tbl` later and use `nm` to replace it with the appropriate `cm` values:

```
tbl <- NULL
for (a in aa){
  for (b in bb) {
    if (any(cc %in% b)) {
      tb <- tibble(nm = names(bb)[b], n1=b[1],n2=b[2],n3=b[3])
      tbl <- bind_rows(tbl,tb)
      }
     }
    }
```

I don't really understand why this doesn't work, because `names(bb)[1]` returns `123` so I figured it would work the same in a loop with `names(bb)[b]`.

Comment: Your for loop `for (b in bb)` loops through each element of `bb`, but if you want to index the vector `names(bb)` you will need to instead write the loop as `for (b in 1:length(bb))` and then use the integer `b` to index both the list `bb` and the vector `names(bb)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy with a base R solution without the explicit loops, would this work?

```
# generate data
aa <- list(c(123, 1), c(234, 1), c(345, 2), c(456, 3))
# cm is an element of bb
bb <- list("123" = c("a", "b", "c"), "234" = c("b", "c", "d"),
           "345" = c("c", "d", "e"), "456" = c("f", "g", "h"),
           cm = c(1, 1, 2))
cc <- c("a", "b", "c")

tbl <- data.frame(
  bb[["cm"]],
  # apply to each element of aa
  do.call(rbind, lapply(aa, function(x, y, c) { # function takes 3 args
    # only elements of bb whose names are in aa[[x]]
    names_y <- as.character(intersect(x, names(y)))
    # turn subset of bb into data.frame
    out <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, y[names_y]))
    # subset rows for which any row element %in% cc
    out <- out[apply(out, 1, function(x, c) any(x %in% c), c)] 
    return(out)
  }, bb, cc))) # pass bb and cc as args to the function in lapply()
names(tbl) <- c("cm", paste0("n", 1:(ncol(tbl) - 1)))
```

gives

```
 > tbl
    cm n1 n2 n3
123  1  a  b  c
234  1  b  c  d
345  2  c  d  e
```

Comment: Thanks! Two issues: **1)** adding `cm=c(1,1,2)` to `bb` is cheating. The real `aa` has 100-1000s of items so I'm essentially going in blind. Plus the need to only pull out the values specified in `cc` precludes e.g. just looping `aa` to make your `cm` vector, as item `456` leads to error: `arguments imply differing number of rows: 4, 3`. **2)** The real `bb` is also 100s of items, and its index starts with `1` `2` etc, so `names_y` will pull any items from `aa` where `names(bb)` intersect with `cm` values. I actually can't think of a way around this...

Comment: Since you want to be adding `cm` to the resulting data.frame, it must stand that `length(cm) == nrow(tbl)` and so it doesn't matter where `cm` is: it can be inside `bb`, `aa`, or just floating around in the global environment. I don't think I understand the other issues, can you please clarify? I am not sure how the lengths of the lists matter?